# Why FMapAVL usage in argument is non strictly positive while list is?

Tags: coq

Consider the following code:

```
Require Import FMapAVL.
Require Import Coq.Structures.OrderedTypeEx.

Module NatMap := FMapAVL.Make(Nat_as_OT).

Inductive ttree (K : Type) (V : Type) :=
| tleaf : ttree K V
| tnode : ttree K V -> K -> V -> ttree K V -> nat -> ttree K V.

Inductive test :=
| test1 : test
| test2 : ttree nat test -> test   
| test3 : list test -> test
| test4 : NatMap.t test -> test.
```

In Coq 8.6, I get `Error: Non strictly positive occurrence of "test" in "NatMap.t test -> test".` I get no error without `test4`.

Why does applying a `NatMap.t` (`FMapAVL` with `nat` keys) constructor to my `test` inductive type creates a non strictly positive occurence while applying `list` constructor or even `ttree` constructor (which is just like internal structure of `FMapAVL`) okay?

What are the common workarounds if I want something like `test4` from my example, preferably ones not requiring me to make my own map implementation like that `ttree`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Coq can't handle some higher-order inductive types as nested inductives - I'm not convinced I fully understand the limitations, but I investigated a bit.

One important fact that helps explain the behavior is that Coq has special support for passing an inductive type to a type constructor. [CPDT's Inductive Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Cpdt.InductiveTypes.html#lab32) chapter explains this in the section on Nested Inductive Types: Coq creates a version of `list` or `ttree` specialized to `test` and pretends you're defining `tree` and these specialized inductives with mutual induction. This generally works fine (such as for your `list` and even `ttree` definitions). It even works for modules, as long as they use "[transparent ascription](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/html/Large.html#lab101)" (and FMapAVL.Make does so). However, it seems to break down when the type is an index instead of a parameter (that is, when the `Type` is to the right of the colon instead of the left):

```
Module Type Transformer.
  Axiom T:Type -> Type.
End Transformer.

Module IdOpaque : Transformer.
  Definition T (t:Type) := t.
End IdOpaque.

Inductive transformer : Type -> Type :=
| MkT : forall t, t -> transformer t .

(* make the argument a parameter *)
Inductive transformer' (t:Type) : Type :=
| MkT' : t -> transformer' t.

Module IdInd <: Transformer.
  Definition T : Type -> Type := transformer.
End IdInd.

Module IdTransparent <: Transformer.
  Definition T (t:Type) : Type := t.
End IdTransparent.

(* works with a simple definition, even inside a module, as long as its
transparent *)
Inductive test1 :=
| mkTest1 (_:IdTransparent.T test1).

(* not strictly positive (Coq can't see definition) *)
Fail Inductive test2 :=
| mkTest2 (_:IdOpaque.T test2).

(* this is pretty much what happens with FMapAVL.Make *)
Fail Inductive test3 :=
| mkTest3 (_:IdInd.T test3).

(* even this fails *)
Fail Inductive test4 :=
| mkTest4 (_:transformer test4).

(* this finally works *)
Inductive test5 :=
| mkTest5 (_:transformer' test5).
```

Comment: I'm still trying to fully understand these mechanisms, but does that mean that to use `FMapAVL` in this manner (or any such structure parametrized by my type), I'd have to duplicate its code manually specialized for my indexes (e.g., `nat`)?

Comment: I found out that it is possible to use `FMapList.Raw T` or `FMapAVL.Raw Z_as_Int T`, however, this removes features from `Coq.FSets.FMapInterface.S`.